# Is it possible to create a Villager who sells pufferfish?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've tried:

```
/summon Villager ~ ~1 ~ {Offers:{Recipes:[{maxUses:10,buy:{id:388,Count:5},sell:{id:**349**,Count:3}}]}}
```

but he only sells regular raw fish.
I've even tried `"349:3"`,`"#0349/3"`, even `"minecraft:fish 1 3"`

But always, he either gives me raw fish, either nothing (just empty slot, game crashes when this slot "bought") So, is that possible? Same thing goes for colored wool/clay, I believe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to follow the normal [item NBT structure](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Player.dat_format#Item_structure) and it should work fine. I believe that your command should be:

```
/summon Villager ~ ~1 ~ {Offers:{Recipes:[{maxUses:10,buy:{id:388,Count:5},sell:{id:349,Damage:3,Count:3}}]}}
```

Answer (score 1):

This entire question was rendered obsolete by the flattening in 1.13, making pufferfish just normal items with the id `pufferfish` and `/summon villager ~ ~1 ~ {Offers:{Recipes:[{maxUses:10,buy:{id:"minecraft:emerald",Count:5},sell:{id:"minecraft:pufferfish",Count:3}}]}}` should just work without futzing with data values.

You also have to give the villager a valid `VillagerData` value in order to be able to trade with them.